# normal probability distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If I as just installed 1400 new lightbulbs with an expected mean lifespan of 60 months and a lifespan standard deviation of 10 months. How many bulbs will need 
 to be replaced after 44 months?

I work this out on excel normsdist(44,60,10,true) but this was wrong I think I need to do something with the 1400 but not sure. thank you

Comment: Probably they want you to just compute the mean number that will need to be replaced. (The wording of the question is somewhat imprecise.)

Comment: When you say replace the mean number can you tell me how to do that is there a formula that I need to use?

Comment: Multiply the probability that an individual bulb needs replacing by $1400$.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of a bulb that it will work after 44 months:

```
normsdist(44,60,10,true)
```

How many of 1400 bulbs

```
1400*normsdist(44,60,10,true)
```

Comment: The worksheet that I have says the answer is 77, and this doesn't come up to his answer either.  I have tried and still lost, any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that an individual bulb needs replacing:
$$P (Z<-1,6) = 0.0548$$
For Your set of data:
$$0.0548\cdot 1400 = 76,72 $$